# ExecWait NSIS with START /WAIT

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to execute :

`ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /k  "START" /WAIT ""c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.exe" -l "c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.log""'`

When I'm trying this:

`ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /k "c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.exe" -l "c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.log""'` ,
it works but i need to close the command console.

Then I tried to replace /k by /c but the ExecWait doesn't wait that this command is finish to continue the installation.
The uninstaller that I want to launch isn't a NSIS installer but the new instaler is.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I'm using this command which seems to work:

```
`ExecWait "$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c ""c:\Program Files\MydDir\Uninstall.exe" -l "c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.log"" & echo. & echo. & pause`
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExecWait` **always** waits for the child process but it does not wait for grandchildren.

I don't understand why you need to use cmd.exe, it is only useful if you are redirecting stdout and in that case you would not need `start /wait` because you would be executing a console application.

Why can't you just use `ExecWait '"c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.exe" -l "c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.log"'` ?

The `/k` switch keeps the console open, `/c` does not, that is the only difference, you would still need the `start /wait` part for non-console applications.

`Start` has silly quote handling, you probably need to do `cmd.exe /c start "" /wait "c:\path\app.exe" "parameters"`

Comment: I can't use `ExecWait '"c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.exe" -l "c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.log"'` because nsis ignores it.

Comment: I'm gonna try your solution.

Comment: `cmd.exe /c start "" /wait "c:\path\app.exe" "parameters"` does the same than `ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c "c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.exe" -l "c:\Program Files\MyDir\Uninstall.log""'`

Comment: No NSIS does not ignore anything, if it does not work then perhaps there is something wrong with the path? 64-bit program files?

Comment: It is 64-bit program files, but I don't thinkthere is something wrong with the path because if I execute in the cmd console there is no problem. Maybe I need the admin rights to execute it.

Comment: Do you not have a "RequestExecutionLevel admin" attribute in your script? ExecWait will fail if your installer is not elevated but the thing you want to run requires elevation...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Create a batch file using fileopen/fileclose and run it with nsExec... something like:

```
  FileOpen $0 C:\Updates\WindowsFeatures\InstallDotNet3.cmd w
              FileWrite $0 'REM This installs the .net 3.x components'
              FileWrite $0 "$\r$\n" ; we write a new line
              FileWrite $0 'DISM /online /LogLevel:4 /Add-package /PackagePath:C:\Updates\WindowsFeatures\Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~.cab /NoRestart /Quiet'
              FileWrite $0 "$\r$\n" ; we write a new line
              FileWrite $0 'DISM /online /LogLevel:4 /Add-package /PackagePath:C:\Updates\WindowsFeatures\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab /NoRestart /Quiet'
              FileClose $0
              DetailPrint "Installing .net 3.x - Please wait"
              nsExec::ExecToStack 'C:\Updates\WindowsFeatures\InstallDotNet3.cmd'

              Pop $0
              Pop $1
              DetailPrint "More Info $0 $1"
```